# VBA omitting last outer loop

Tags: vba, for-loop

I am requesting assistance as to why the last outer loop of the following code is omitted. This code is part of a healthcare simulation, which uses VBA to iterate through combinations of parameters to generate sensitivity analyses. I have 3 other sensitivity analyses operating without issue. Notably, the sub `call_transplant_surv` is a highly conserved program that operates without issue in many other operatiions not shown here. I have tried skeletonizing the code to isolate the issue without success. I have not noted an error on the sheets that would cause failure at certain values of `txp1b`.

```
Sub twoway1()

        'delay in list and 1B VAD txp rate

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

        Dim i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
        Dim prob_bin As Byte, delay_list As Byte, status_2_bin As Byte, elective_days As Byte, first_day As Byte
        Dim timestart As Double, timeall As Double, twoway1 As Integer, twoway2 As Integer, delay_i As Integer


        'begin time counter
        timestart = Time

        'set values
        prob_bin = 0            'probabilistic model = 1
        delay_list = 0          'set to  to begin at 30 given loop
        status_2_bin = 0        'normal values = 0
        elective_days = 30      'fixed value of 1A days allowed
        first_day = 30          'first day elective time is used, incremented in the macro w/o a variable
        posttxp_death = 1
        twoway1 = 1
        twoway2 = 0
        txp1b = 0
        delay_i = 0

        time_measure = 0       'measurement time (e.g. at 0 days all parameters are measured, 30 days all measured, etc.)
        timemeas_inc = 30      'increment of the measurement time (e.g. every 30 days- 30, 60, 90,....

        counter = 1

            'enter settings into model
            Sheets("settings").Range("C27").Value = prob_bin
            Sheets("settings").Range("C28").Value = delay_list
            Sheets("settings").Range("C29").Value = status_2_bin
            Sheets("settings").Range("C30").Value = elective_days
            Sheets("settings").Range("C31").Value = first_day
            Sheets("settings").Range("C32").Value = posttxp_death
            Sheets("settings").Range("C44").Value = twoway1
            Sheets("settings").Range("C45").Value = twoway2

            calculate

            'enter two loops to control the parameters
            'enter two loops to control the parameters
                For txp1b = 0.05 To 0.3 Step 0.05
                    For delay_i = 0 To 360 Step 90

                    Sheets("settings").Range("C31").Value = delay_i + 30
                    Sheets("settings").Range("C28").Value = delay_i
                    Sheets("1B>TXP Weib").Range("J20").Value = txp1b

                    calculate

                    'transplant survival calcs
                    call_txp_surv

                    'enter measurement loop
                    For i = 1 To 61

                        'place time measured
                        Sheets("settings").Range("AD4").Value = time_measure

                        'speed up calcs part 2
                        calculate

                        'record simulation results into sheet delay_list Row/column
                        Sheets("twoway1").Activate
                        Sheets("twoway1").Range(Cells(counter + 1, 1), Cells(counter + 1, 45)).Value = Sheets("settings").Range("M4:BE4").Value

                        'increment the time point for data recording
                        time_measure = time_measure + timemeas_inc

                        'increment counter for correct placement of next loop of results
                        counter = counter + 1

                    Next i

                time_measure = 0

                Next
            Next

            time_all = Time - timestart
            'Sheets("twoway1").Range("AU2").Value = time_all

            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is using a non-integer loop counter - my guess is that the loop is exiting early because of a floating point error:

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim i As Double
    For i = 0.05 To 0.3 Step 0.05
        Debug.Print i
    Next
End Sub
```

My recommendation would be to use integer iterations and then calculate the working value separately:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 6
    txp1b = i * 0.05
    '...
Next
```

Comment: You may also use [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251687.aspx) or [Currency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264338.aspx) data types which use integers as base types and are not subjects to floating point error propagation.

Comment: @VincentG - That would also work in this case (I'm not exactly clear on whether there's implicit casting when it compiles and where), but keep in mind that the counter itself will be treated as a scaled type, but any literals need to be [hinted](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201611281711181796862) to the correct type (or explicitly declared as scaled variables).  I.e.:  `For i = 0.05@ To 0.3@ Step 0.05@`. In the OP's code it's implicitly (undeclared) a `Variant`, so it's being treated as a `Double`.